# Construct a multiplication operator which has dense point spectrum

Tags: measure-theory, operator-theory, spectral-theory

By a *multiplication operator* here we mean an operator

$$Af(t)=m(t)f(t), \qquad f \in D(A)=\{x \in L^2(\mathbb{R} \mid m(t)f(t) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}$$

where $m$ is a Borel measurable function on the line. Motivated by Exercise 3.13, pag.104 of Teschl's book ([link](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-schroe/)) I'm trying to construct such an operator having all rationals as eigenvalues.

> This amounts to find a Borel measurable function $m$ such that $m^{-1}(\lambda)$ has positive measure for all rational $\lambda$. How to do that?

I find constructing an *abstract* linear operator on some separable Hilbert space $H$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ as point spectrum not too difficult: take an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ and an enumeration $\{r_n\}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ then define

$$Af=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r_n(f, e_n)e_n, \qquad f \in D(A)=\left\{g \in H \mid \sum_{n=0}^\infty r_n^2\left\lvert(g, e_n)\right\rvert^2 < \infty\right\}.$$

But how to go from this to a function $m$ as prescribed above?

Thank you.

Comment: It's late here, but if you're just looking for such a Borel function $m$, partition your domain (the reals) into countably many pairwise disjoint Borel sets $A_n$ of positive measure and put $m = \sum_n \lambda_n [A_n]$ where $\{\lambda_n\}_n$ is an enumeration of the rationals and $[A_n]$ is the characteristic function of $A_n$.

Comment: @Theo: Thank you very much! This is a bit embarrassing, though: I should have thought a bit more by myself - it wasn't difficult. For example, choosing $A_n=(n, n+1]$, the function $m$ you construct above is a step function taking all rational values. The corresponding multiplication operator is similar to the operator $A$ of my post if we take $e_n(t)=[(n, n+1]](t)$, which indeed is an orthonormal system of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (it is not complete, but that doesn't matter). 
$$$$
Now it is perfectly clear, next time I will try to think twice before posting a question! Thank you again.